# How to find licensing information on EU-funded projects?

Tags: licensing

How can I find-out the licensing information on a product that's funded by the EU?

For example, enormous amounts of [research](https://www.researchgate.net/search/publication?q=eurotrough) has been published about the "Euro Trough" -- a [linear parabolic solar concentrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentrated_solar_power#Parabolic_trough).

Most of this research was funded by the State, but I can't find the licensing information anywhere.

Who legally owns the intellectual property for products funded by the EU? And is there some authoritative source (eg website) where I can figure out what the licensing information is?

Answer (score 6):

I'm reasonably sure there is no authorative source for anything like this in this generality. Only in recent years a move is made to require researchers and contractors of grants to follow more open standards so that research results and code produced is made available to the public in an open manner. This is still not the norm (everywhere). And there is no central registry.

Thus: the copyright will need to be indicated within the repositories, on the pages, in the documents or the sources you want to use, thus in the usual places. If you find no information, the general rule applies: "all rights reserved". It's tedious, but it never hurts to ask the authors / copyright owners if the information is unclear or missing. It definitely is worth continuing to lobby for public availability and access to results and works funded by public money.